# How to get duration of YouTube video via YouTubeDataApi v3 in Android?

Tags: android, json, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I am using YouTubeData Api v3 to get id, title, description and thumbnail of a video from search results. Now I want to get the duration of a video as well which I am not able to achieve with the following code.

How to get the duration of video also? I have set the parts and fields too as shown in code to receive the property.

```
private int youTubeConnector() {
    try {
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
            }
        }).setApplicationName(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)).build();

    } catch(ExceptionInInitializerError e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } catch(RuntimeException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }

    try {
        query = youtube.search().list("id,snippet,contentDetails");
        query.setKey(Constants.YOUTUBE);
        query.setType("video");
        query.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description,snippet/thumbnails/high/url,contentDetails/duration),nextPageToken,prevPageToken,pageInfo");

        return 1;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}

public List<YouTubeVideoItem> search(String keywords) {
    query.setQ(keywords);
    query.setMaxResults(YOUTUBE_MAXRESULTS);

    if(nextPage == true) {
        query.setPageToken(nextPageToken);
        nextPage = false;
    }
    else if(previousPage == true) {
        query.setPageToken(previousPageToken);
        previousPage = false;
    }

    try {
        SearchListResponse response = query.execute();
        nextPageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
        previousPageToken = response.getPrevPageToken();

        List<SearchResult> results = response.getItems();
        List<YouTubeVideoItem> items = new ArrayList<YouTubeVideoItem>();

        if(results != null) {
            items = setItemsList(results.iterator());
        }
        return items;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private List<YouTubeVideoItem> setItemsList(Iterator<SearchResult> iteratorSearchResults) {
    List<YouTubeVideoItem> tempSetItems = new ArrayList<>();

    while(iteratorSearchResults.hasNext()) {
        SearchResult singleVideo = iteratorSearchResults.next();
        ResourceId rId = singleVideo.getId();

        try{
            if (rId.getKind().equals("youtube#video")) {
                YouTubeVideoItem item = new YouTubeVideoItem();
                Thumbnail thumbnail = singleVideo.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getHigh();

                item.setId(singleVideo.getId().getVideoId());
                item.setTitle(singleVideo.getSnippet().getTitle());
                item.setDescription(singleVideo.getSnippet().getDescription());
                item.setThumbnailURL(thumbnail.getUrl());


                tempSetItems.add(item);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return tempSetItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource), the [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint does not provide the duration property of any video item that it includes within the result set yielded back to the caller.

For to access the [`duration`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration) property of any videos you're interested in, you have to use the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint queried appropriately.

Note that this latter endpoint accepts its [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) parameter to be a comma-separated list of video IDs. Therefore, for a set of `N` video IDs, you don't have to issue `N` calls to `Videos.list`, but, if `N <= 50`, only one such call that has an `id` parameter assigned properly.